# Losing session cookie in iframe when using .net6

Tags: asp.net-core, iframe, cors, .net-6.0, samesite

I have a cross site iframe, however it doesn't persist with session.

I've checked multiple answers on here and it's likely due to same site cookie policy however setting this to the recommended settings isn't doing the trick.

It's fine when the iframe is on a non-locahost domain, with it's src using localhost via visual studio, but when deploying to azure the session doesn't persist.

Here's my session and cors options from program.cs

```
//Session
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});

var corsPolicy = "CORS";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicy,
                    policy =>
                    {
                        policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                        policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                        policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    });
});

....
....
....

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(corsPolicy);

app.UseSession();
```

Comment: Did the Iframe site is inside the same domain as the main site?

Comment: No it is cross domain @BrandoZhang

Comment: Could you please tell me which browser you have used? Chrome or edge ?